# Global sections of covering spaces

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $p:C\to X$ be a covering space having a global section $s:X\to C$. I can show that this implies that $s(X)$ is disconnected from the rest of $C$.

Is there any reference where this is explicitly proven? I need this result for a paper and would like to reference it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of a reference in print, but I answered a similar question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256951/about-covering-maps-and-sections/257419#257419.  Worst case scenario, you could reference MSE itself.