# Show that a continuous map from covering space is a homeomorphism if fundamental group is finite.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I have this question:

Let $X$ be a topological space, $X$ path connected, locally path connected. Let $Y$ be the covering space with $p:Y \rightarrow X $ be the covering map.

I want to show that if $f$ is a continuous map from Y to Y such that $pf=f$ then $f$ is a homeomorphism in following cases:

a) fundamental group of $Y$ is finite

b) $p$ is normal covering

c)Image of $p$ has finite index.

How should I solve this problem. Any hints.

---

**Edits**

I found this question ( I did a Google search). [image]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256951/if-a-covering-map-has-a-section-is-it-a-1-fold-cover

Comment: How this question is related.

Comment: One problem that i see with what you ask is that $pf$ goes from Y to X while $f$ goes from Y to Y.  Is there any relation between X and Y?

Comment: Oh i see it should be $pf = p$