# Bijection from (proper) Lorentz group to PSL(2,C)

Tags: representation-theory, covering-spaces, quantum-field-theory, semi-riemannian-geometry

It is well known that $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is the universal cover of $SO^+(1,3)$, see for example the  Wikipedia page on the Lorentz group [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Homomorphisms_and_isomorphisms). The map goes like this (some of this is not standard notation):

First, establish a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ and the set $M_{s.a.}(2,\mathbb{C})$ of self-adjoint 2x2 matrices with complex entries via

\begin{align*}
\sigma:\mathbb{R}^{1,3}&\to M_{s.a.}(2,\mathbb{C})
\\
(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)&\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}x_0+x_3&x_1-ix_2 \\ x_1+ix_2 & x_0-x_3\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

An important property of $\sigma$ is that it preserves the metric in the sense that
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{det}(\sigma(x))=x^2:=x_0^2-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2
\end{equation}

Then there is a natural action of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ on $M_{s.a.}(2,\mathbb{C})$ by
\begin{align*}
\lambda:SL_2(\mathbb{C})&\to \big(M_{s.a.}(2,\mathbb{C})\to M_{s.a.}(2,\mathbb{C})\big) 
\\
A&\mapsto (X\mapsto AXA^*) 
\end{align*}

The determinant property guarantees that it is well-defined. Then the so-called spinor representation is the induced map

\begin{align*}
\Lambda:SL_2(\mathbb{C})&\to \big(\mathbb{R}^{1,3}\to\mathbb{R}^{1,3}\big) 
\\
A&\mapsto \sigma^{-1}\circ\lambda(A)\circ\sigma
\end{align*}

It is then shown that the $\mathrm{Im}(\Lambda)=SO^+(1,3)$ and $\ker(\Lambda)=\{\pm1\}$. The explicit matrix elements of $\Lambda(A)$ can be calculated in terms of taking traces of various combinations of Pauli matrices (see the wiki for details). The 1st isomorphism theorem then implies that the quotient group $PSL_2(\mathbb{C}):=SL_2(\mathbb{C})/ \{\pm 1\}$ is isomorphic to the image of $\Lambda$
\begin{align*}
\tilde{\Lambda}:PSL_2(\mathbb{C})&\to SO^+(1,3)
\\
[A]&\mapsto \Lambda(A)
\end{align*}

**My question is**: How can we describe the reverse map $\tilde{\Lambda}^{-1}(L)=\{\pm A_L\}$? This is given as an *exercise* on pg  134 of this book

*Bogoljubov, Nikolaj N.; Logunov, Anatolij A.; Todorov, Ivan T.*, [**Introduction to axiomatic quantum field theory. Authorized translation from the Russian original by Stephen A. Fulling and Ludmilla G. Popova. Edited by Stephen A. Fulling**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/43332), Mathematical Physics Monograph Series 18. Reading, MA: Benjamin. xxvi, 707 p. (1975). [ZBL1114.81300](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1114.81300).

Is there an explicit formula for the 2x2 matrix in the fiber above a Lorentz transform in terms of the its matrix elements? We know that $\tilde{\Lambda}$ is invertible for abstract reasons, but I was hoping for something a bit more concrete. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by a section? A continuous map $s$ such that $\Lambda \circ  s = id$? Or just a **fumction** with this property?

Comment: Good point. I guess I'd be fine with any map, but it'd be nice if it were continuous.

Comment: (Continuous) sections are homeomorphisms. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/256951. Thus there is no global section here (but of course there are local sections). I suggest that you edit your question and remove the misleading phrase "section".  You want to express $\Lambda^{-1}(L)$ explicitly in terms of $L$.

Comment: I forgot that section has a different meaning than how I was using it, thank you. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: You need to first know that every member of $SO^+(1,3)$ can be decomposed as $RZS$ where $R,S$ are rotations and $Z$ is a boost in some direction.  The rotations are mapped from $SU(2)$ inside $SL(2,\Bbb{C})$.  These can also be written as $\exp((i\theta/2) \vec \mu \cdot \vec\sigma)$ where $\vec \mu$ is a unit vector in $\Bbb{R}^3$ and $\vec\sigma$ the Pauli spin matrices.  Then the boosts are mapped from $\exp((\psi/2) \vec \eta \cdot \vec\sigma)$ where $\vec\eta$ is also a unit vector in $\Bbb{R}^3$ giving the direction of boost.

Comment: Ah okay, that would definitely help. How is it shown that every element of $SO^+(1,3)$ is of that form? I've seen the approach of exponentiating the generators, say $b$ and $r$, of boosts/rotations to write $L=exp(i\mu\cdot r+i\eta\cdot b)$. But I'd think that this doesn't imply we can write it as $RB$ since the generators of boosts and rotations don't commute with each other.